# Call system UNIX - File copy in C

Tags: c

I try to create a copy of a source file but the target file is always empty.

The algorithm is: read from STDIN and write to source file, then read on this file and write the text in target file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 8192

int main(){
    int fdsource, fdtarget;
    int n, nr;
    char buff[BUFFSIZE];

    fdsource = open("source.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); // Create and open a source file in read/write
    if (fdsource < 0){
        printf("Source file open error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fdtarget = open("target.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); // Create and open a source file in write only
    if (fdtarget < 0){
        printf("Target file open error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("\nInsert text:\n");
    while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFFSIZE)) > 0){ // Read from STDIN and write to source file
        if ((write(fdsource, buff, n)) != n){
            printf("Source file write error!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    while ((read(fdsource, buff, n)) > 0){ // Read from source file and write to target file
        if ((write(fdtarget, buff, n)) != n){
            printf("Source file open error!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    close(fdsource);
    close(fdtarget);
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also,`read()` and `write()` do not return `int`, they return `ssize_t`.  Nor do they take an `int` as the third argument - they both take `size_t` as the third argument.There's a reason the documentation says `ssize_t` and `size_t`:  http://linux.die.net/man/2/read

Comment: I solved simply closing the source file and then open it when i had to read it again. Anyway thanks for help :-)

Comment: You might like to add your own answer though, and even accept it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is "You have opened both the file in initial stage". To solve the problem just open the source file in the write mode and write all the data, then close and reopen the source file in read mode, Then open the target file in the write mode. 
The modified code is given below and it was not tested

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFSIZE 8192

int main(){
    int fdsource, fdtarget;
    int n;
    char buff[BUFFSIZE];

    fdsource = open("source.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); // Create and open a source file in read/write
    if (fdsource < 0){
        printf("Source file open error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nInsert text:\n");
    while ((n = read(STDIN_FILENO, buff, BUFFSIZE)) > 0){ // Read from STDIN and write to source file
        if ((write(fdsource, buff, n)) != n){
            printf("Source file write error!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    close(fdsource);
    fdsource = open("source.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); // Create and open a source file in read/write
    if (fdsource < 0){
        printf("Source file open error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    fdtarget = open("target.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); // Create and open a source file in write only
    if (fdtarget < 0){
        printf("Target file open error!\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    while ((read(fdsource, buff, n)) > 0){ // Read from source file and write to target file
        if ((write(fdtarget, buff, n)) != n){
            printf("Source file open error!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    close(fdsource);
    close(fdtarget);
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

If am wrong anywhere use the logic mentioned above.